# Simultaneous Differential Equation $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{x+y+t}=\frac{dt}{t}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$
\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{x+y+t}=\frac{dt}{t}
$$ 
I was given this problem but don't know how to start, I'm not sure but I tried it like 
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{x+y+t}\tag{1}$$
$$\frac{dt}{t}=\frac{dy}{x+y+t}\tag{2}$$

now if I subtract $(1)$ from $(2)$ I just get 
$$\frac{dt}{t}=\frac{dx}{x}$$
which is useless I think.

Comment: $\int\frac{dt}{t}=\int\frac{dx}{x}\Rightarrow \ln x=\ln t+\ln c$ finally you have $x=tc$
Now take equation (2) and put $x=tc$ you will get a new equation, solve that equation

Comment: @Chiranjeev $\frac{dt}{dy}=\frac{t}{t+y+t}$ ok... but from here?

Comment: @Mickey Nope, $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{ct + y + t}{t} = 1+c + \frac{y}{t}$. Have you heard about homogeneous first order equations?

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\frac{dt}{t}=\int\frac{dx}{x}\Rightarrow \ln x=\ln t+\ln c\\
x=tc$$
Now,Using equation (2) we have,
$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt} = \frac{ct + y + t}{t} \\
\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}=1+c + \frac{y}{t}\\
\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}-\frac{y}{t}=1+c$$

Which Linear in $y$,So, $$IF=e^{\int \frac {-1}{t}\mathrm dt}=\frac {1}{t}$$

Hence General solution of this equation is, $$\frac {y}{t}=\int\frac{1+c}{t}\mathrm dt+c'$$

.